# Semantic UI React - Search: Show results above Search component?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I have Search component at the bottom of the page. SPA, no scroll. Is it possible to move search results above Search control?

**Edit**
Rishat, please take a look (only one and half results are visible):
[image: Search results - screenshot]

Please find Search code here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hsqdtb

Comment: Please show us the code that displays search results not above the Search control.

Comment: I'm looking for something like **upward** property in the **Dropdown** (Semantic UI React) component.

Comment: In this case, I'd suggest hacking `.ui .results` element's styles. For example, setting `top` to "auto" and `bottom` to 40px would move it upwards, that would probably make a good start towards the exact solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you very much Rishat Muhametshin.**

I thought that I had already tried this before publishing the question. The magic word I missed is !important.

```
.ui .results {
    top:auto !important;
    bottom:30px !important;
}
```

[image: Search results on the top]